# Add user properties to Azure Active Directory for SCIM provisioning (HiBob)

Tags: azure-active-directory, scim

I'm trying to setup a user lifecycle flow that will allow me to create an Azure Active Directory user (Member, not Guest) when an employee is created in our HRIS tool (HiBob). There is a pre-existing integration which is enabled and allows us to get basic information (name, location, etc.).

In the HRIS system we also store some more unique data that I would like to be added to the users AAD profile (maybe an emergency contact for example) that we can then use to provision other applications (like Slack).

My issue is trying to create these custom property fields. I have read about Azure B2C as well as directory schema, custom security extensions and using MS Graph. None of these seem to be totally relevant to my situation.

FYI we are fully cloud, so Azure AD Connect is also not an option.

Answer (score 0):

To store custom data in Azure AD objects such as users you can leverage [Azure AD Directory Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview#directory-azure-ad-extensions) in tandem with [Azure AD Provisioning trough SCIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/sync-scim).